# How to debug javascript in browsers that don't have a console interface?

Tags: debugging, browser, internet

It's unbelievable but my company is still building web app on IE 6. Although the online dashboard for IE 6 is limited in functionality, I've found ***extremely*** difficult to debug anything on it. It's probably the most challenging task in my career, and I'm considering to leave the job because it takes way too much time to do anything.

On Chrome, I could simply add a breakpoint in a JavaScript source, but this is not possible on IE 6. Nothing on IE 6 seems make sense, for example, the CSS simply don't work. There is no web console.

How did the programmers 10-15 years ago managed to debug anything? Currently, I'll have to show an alert box to debug a loop, so I'd have to close off the alert box for each iteration of the loop. 100 alert boxes for a loop with 100 iterations...

Comment: Step 1 - stop trying to support IE6

Comment: append to a "console" element in the page?

Comment: @Dannnno Not possible because IE 6 is still being used by some of the largest corporations.

Comment: @HorusKol What do you mean? I'm talking about a console that I can test variables and see print outs from running a piece of code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how to use a software tool.

Comment: yeah, and you can replicate that by having some element container in your page and instead of relying on "console.log" you append that information to that element container

Comment: @Snowman No it's not, it's more about asking how to address the IE 6 softwares. This is a serious issue, because we've already got used to things like Chrome debugging. But IE 6 is still being used. In this question we're discussing how to tackle it in the 2015 world.

Comment: @HorusKol I don't really follow the idea, maybe you'd want to add it as an answer.

Comment: @Snowman I didn't ask for advice on how to use IE 6 nor how to use the debugging tools in IE 6. I'm clearly asking for advices on how to do works more efficiently on the old browser.

Comment: There really isn't any justification whatsoever to program to IE6 anymore.  Microsoft has long since stopped supporting it; [this page](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) puts the market penetration at 0.76 percent.  Microsoft even has a [death march page for IE6](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/ie6countdown/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're right but that 0.76 percent still include, for example, Qantas, the largest airline in Australia. They're our client, and demand a solution only in IE 6.

Comment: They're exposing themselves to huge risks.  Has anyone explained that to them?

Comment: pretty sure the number of browsers that don't have a console interface for javascript is equally small - but that might help with certain prejudices against IE6 (which should be killed with fire)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I guess the OP is not in a position to make any suggestions against supporting IE6, no matter how well-founded the reasons are. But let's inform some black hats that Quantas is still using IE6, some people have to learn it the hard way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, lets go a bit further:

There are two kinds of browsers - ones that provide a console interface with a log method, and ones that don't.

Right before you do any other javascript, have the following code (assuming you have jQuery - adapt if you use something else):

```
if (!window.console) {
   var consoleElement = $("<div>");
   consoleElement.addClass("console"); // use CSS to position and style this element for testing

   $("body").append(consoleElement);

   console = {
       log: function(message) {
           var messageElement = $("<span>");
           messageElement.addClass("console")
               .text(message);

           $("#console").append(messageElement);
       }
   };
}
```

A more complete approach can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817235/184124

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried downloading the **Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar**? It will help you debug and troubleshoot your webpages on IE6 or other versions: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Answer (score 2):

Use Internet Explorer 11 and have it emulate Internet Explorer 5.

F12 -> Emulation -> Document Mode

Internet Explorer will then behave like Internet Explorer 5/6, but will offer you all the modern debugging tools.

Regarding your question

> How did the programmers 10-15 years ago managed to debug anything?

Javascript applications used to be far simpler back then, so javascript debugging capabilities didn't need to be complex either. There wasn't that much you could do with Javascript anyway. Lots of features we take for granted now didn't exist back then. More complex applications were usually implemented purely server-sided or with plugins like <strike>Adobe</strike> Macromedia Flash.

Because CSS was so poor and inconsistent back then, lots of people abused tables nested in tables nested in tables to create layouts. Although frowned upon today, this was the most reliable and convenient way to get elements to where you wanted them to be.